# многофайловый проект и функции вне класса

Tags: c++, компоновщик, линковка

Что-то я немного запутался.

Если я создаю функцию, к которой обращаюсь из класса, сам класс и `main()`, откуда вызываю этот класс в одном файле, то проблем нет.
Если же я создаю функцию и класс в одном файле, а вызываю класс из другого - то ошибка линковки.

Конечно, можно запихнуть функцию внутрь класса и будет работать, но дело в том, что я планирую её сделать для разных классов, ибо она одинаковая для них.
Пример очень упрощён, чтобы не путаться в лишнем коде.

**файл Source.cpp**

```
#include "Source1.cpp"
int main(){abc a;}
```

**файл Source1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
void print() { std::cout << "bdca"; }
class abc
{
public:
        abc() { print(); }
};
```

И куча ошибок линковщика.

> Ошибка LNK2005 "void __cdecl print(void)" (?print@@YAXXZ) уже определен в Source.obj   temp    C:\Users\lexpartizan\source\repos\temp\temp\Source1.obj 1

В общем, как сделать функцию вне класса в другом файле?

Comment: ну и зачем вы инклюдите cpp-файл? Познакомтесь с хэдэрами и все проблемы решаться сами-собой

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться с хэдерами. Просто хотелось всё держать в одном файле.

Comment: Вы включили один `.cpp` файл в другой, и при этом еще и отдельно скомпилировали включенный `.cpp` файл. Неудивительно, что получились множественные определения.

Comment: как насчет псевдокласса со статическими функциями?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include "Source1.cpp"
```

Вот это приводит к тому, что компилятор видит два файла:

```
#include <iostream>
void print() { std::cout << "bdca"; }
class abc
{
public:
        abc() { print(); }
};
```

и

```
#include <iostream>
void print() { std::cout << "bdca"; }
class abc
{
public:
        abc() { print(); }
};

int main(){abc a;}
```

В результате он дважды компилирует класс, `print` и отдает линковщику, который не понимает, как ему выбрать, какую `print` использовать - из какого файла?

Вот вы бы на его месте как поступили?

А правильно - во включаемых файлах давать только объявления, ну, и inline-определения. Т.е. у вас

**Source.h**

```
#include <iostream>
void print();
class abc
{
public:
        abc() { print(); }
};
```

**Source.cpp**

```
#include "Source.h"
int main() { abc a; }
```

**Source1.cpp**

```
#include "Source.h" // В принципе, не обязательно - можно <iostream>
void print() { std::cout << "bdca"; }
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду учить хэдеры. Честно говоря, хотелось не плодить сущности, чтобы всё в одном файле. Могу ли я просто вынести классы с описанными внутри них методами в файл.h или методы тоже в .cpp придётся выносить?

Comment: Методы с телами внутри класса рассматриваются как inline и вполне располагаются в заголовочном файле. Определения НЕ-inline методов должны быть в cpp-файле.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Обращайтесь :) Если ответ устроил - помечайте как принятый...

Comment: Спасибо, что подсказали, что надо принять ответ, а то я тут впервые, не разобрался ещё где репутацию плюснуть можно и тд.

Answer (score 3):

В "классическом" заголовочном файле нельзя определять не-inline переменные или функции с внешним связыванием. При включении такого заголовочного файла в несколько единиц трансляции вы получите ошибку множественного определения, что и произошло в вашем случае.

В заголовочном файле можно определять

1. Inline переменные или функции

   ```
   inline void print() { std::cout << "bdca"; }

   inline int a = 42;
   ```
2. Переменные или функции с внутренним связыванием

   ```
   static void print() { std::cout << "bdca"; }

   const int a = 42;
   static int b = 123;
   ```

   имея при этом в виду, что в этом случае каждая единица трансляции получит свой отдельный экземпляр переменной или функции.

Comment: вы правы, думал речь идет о классах