# Правильное включение файлов в C++. Ошибка "метод уже определён"

Tags: c++

Есть функция clear_screen(), которая находится в файле for_screen.h. Есть файл ConsoleApllication8.cpp, в котором находится функция main. Я включаю for_screen.h в ConsoleApllication8.cpp и вызываю из него (for_screen.h) функцию clear_screen()
И получаю ошибку

> for_screen.obj : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl clear_screen(void)" (?clear_screen@@YAXXZ) уже определен в ConsoleApplication8.obj

Я пытался переименовать файл, изменить его расширение, но ничего не помогает. Что мне делать?

Вот код: 
for_screen.h:

```
#ifndef for_screen
#define for_screen

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void clear_screen() {
    system("cls");
}

void cursorSetPos(short int x, short int y) {
    //COORD coord = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {x, y});
}
#endif
```

ConsoleApplication8.cpp:

```
#include "for_screen.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cursorSetPos(1, 2);
    clear_screen();
}
```

Comment: Ну посмотрите в учебник! где вы видели, чтоб включали `.cpp` файлы? Дело не в расширении, а в содержимом! Включают только заголовочные файлы с объявлениями!

Comment: @Harry Я изменил расширение на .h, и ничего не изменилось. Ошибка всё ещё возникает. более того, она возникает даже после того, как я добавил #ifndef, #define и #endif.

Comment: Прежде, чем что-то исправлять, следует понять в чем заключается проблема. А для этого нужно почитать какой-нибудь ликбез по организации кода в С++ и стадиям его компиляции.

Comment: @user7860670 Я понятия не имею что такое ликбез, также как понятия не имею, что значит "стадиям его компиляцию"

Comment: Ну тогда начните с https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7

Comment: Еще раз копирую свой комментарий: ***Дело не в расширении, а в содержимом! Включают только заголовочные файлы с объявлениями!***. Перечитайте, вникните. Что вы включаете? Что в вашем файле? Объявления или определения? И да, см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/871371/195342

Comment: *"понятия не имею что такое ликбез"* Дык погуглите? Вообще, у вас какая-то проблема с кодом. Без кода мы не можем помочь.

Comment: @Harry чем объявления отличаются от определений?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я добавил код, который вы просили.

Comment: `void clear_screen() { system("cls"); }` — определение, `void clear_screen();` — объявление.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "for_screen.h"
```

приводит к тому, что компилятор видит два файла:

```
#ifndef for_screen
#define for_screen

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void clear_screen() {
    system("cls");
}

void cursorSetPos(short int x, short int y) {
    //COORD coord = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {x, y});
}
#endif
```

и

```
#ifndef for_screen
#define for_screen

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

void clear_screen() {
    system("cls");
}

void cursorSetPos(short int x, short int y) {
    //COORD coord = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {x, y});
}
#endif

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cursorSetPos(1, 2);
    clear_screen();
}
```

В результате он дважды компилирует `clear_screen()` и `cursorSetPos()` и отдает линковщику, который не понимает, как ему выбрать, какую `clear_screen()` использовать - из какого файла?

Вот вы бы на его месте как поступили?

А правильно - во включаемых файлах давать только объявления, ну, и inline-определения. Т.е. у вас

**for_screen.h**

```
#ifndef for_screen
#define for_screen

void clear_screen();

void cursorSetPos(short int x, short int y);
#endif
```

**for_screen.cpp**

```
#include "for_screen.h"
#include <windows.h>

void clear_screen() {
    system("cls");
}

void cursorSetPos(short int x, short int y) {
    //COORD coord = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), {x, y});
}
```

и

**ConsoleApplication8.cpp**:

```
#include "for_screen.h"

int main() {
    cursorSetPos(1, 2);
    clear_screen();
}
```

Comment: Можно. Объедините все в один файл и не морочьте голову. Вот почему вас нее нервирует, что вы включаете тот же `iostream` или `windows.h`, в которых только объявления, но вот свои файлы обязательно хотите именно так? Знаете что, а делайте `#include "for_screen.cpp"`, только не компилируйте этот `for_screen.cpp` отдельно. Все будет работать. Устраивает? Зачем вам вообще многофайловые проекты?

Comment: многофайловые проекты мне нужны, чтобы потом, когда кода будет много, не мучиться и не искать в огромном файле нужную мне вещь.

Comment: Ну вот видите, вы уже начинаете понимать, что к чему :) И почему надо отделять мух от варенья... Пару комментариев выше вы страстно хотели именно огромные файлы!

Comment: Возможно, вы меня неправильно поняли, но я не хотел огромных файлов. Я разделяю проект на несколько файлов только потому что в будущем там будет много кода.